# How to store an enum with an associated value in @SceneStorage

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm new to SwiftUI and Swift development, although I have lots of other development experience. I am trying to store the value of an enumeration in Swift(UI) using the `@SceneStorage` property wrapper.

It is my first macOS app, and I would like to do this because the sidebar of the app I am tinkering around with represents documents that may be grouped in Core Data by some group ID (like a folder ID), or they may be pseudo- or meta-groups of documents, such as "All" or "Recent". I would like my app to remember which document group is selected.

The enum looks like this:

```
enum DocumentGrouping {
    case all
    case recent
    case folder(UUID)
}
```

...and my `@SceneStorage` declaration looks like this:

```
@SceneStorage("selection") private var selectedDocumentGrouping: DocumentGrouping
```

However, Swift(UI) complains "No exact matches in call to initializer." How do I get around this?

Or, if this is not a good approach, how can I rework my sidebar's `List(selection: $selectedDocumentGrouping)` to best implement this?

Comment: `@SceneStorage` and `@AppStorage` are basically wrappers for saving in UserDefaults. You can do this manually. this might help: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/12/2/reading-and-writing-basics-userdefaults